# Real Time Notification Using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, websocket, long-polling, server-sent-events, real-time-data

I want to build a real-time application where user gets notified for each update on the server. User is logged in on site and would be notified in real time(one to one).

What is the best way to achieve this?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 for server side and I need a better and reliable option to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this depends on your exact requirements. Without knowing that, an option to do it would be by using [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/).

Part of the SignalR resource page also contains [a demo for using SignalR with MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc). Other resources for SignalR are available online.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan!!

I had already explored SignalR, but we have Window Server 2008 and SignalR only work with 2012 & .NET 4.5.

Do you know any other option that work on 2008?

Comment: @vijaychauhan: maybe [another websocket library](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/WebSockets) could meet your needs? Otherwise you might need to implement some [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) solution.

Comment: @Bogdan the link you provided seems to be dead